# Select Option PHP

Tags: php, html-select

I am implementing some code but for some reason when I choose an option it retrieves correctly the row I want but I can't select the "Select" to show all the results again.

For example, I have "SELECT", "A", "B". When I choose A or B it shows me the A or B results but when I want it to show all clicking "SELECT" it shows me the last result.

EDIT: And when I choose an option, the option stays "SELECT" and not the one I selected...

The code is:

```
        <td class="titletable2" >GRUPO<font color="#F25C09">: </font></td>
<td>
    <select name="grupo_id_grupo" id="id_grupo" onchange="document.getElementById('pesquisaform').submit()">
        <option value="-1" 
        <?php if ($_SESSION["filtro"]['id_'] == '-1' || !isset($_SESSION["filtro"]['grupo_id_grupo'])) { echo "selected"; } ?>>
        <?php echo "<option value = '".$grupo['nome']."'";?></option>
        <?php 
            $DB = new DataBase();
            $listagrupos = $DB->select_associative_data("grupo", "*");
            $DB->disconnect();

             foreach ($listagrupos as $grupo){
                echo "<option value = '".$grupo['id_grupo']."'";

                if( isset($_SESSION["filtro"]['id_grupo']) && $_SESSION["filtro"]['id_grupo'] == $grupo['id_grupo']){ echo "selected";};

                echo ">".$grupo['nome']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you show print_R($listagrupos); First time and when you select something.

Comment: Hi Luís. It seems you are messing up with server side and client side scripts. I see in your code that you have a submit function in javascript to submit the form of your `select` tag but I can't see the code where you set the `$_SESSION["filtro"]` This code will be good to see in order to provide you a proper answer. E seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow.

Comment: @Jorge Campos, for some reason i put an "<?php echo "<option value = '".$grupo['nome']."'";?>" inside the <option> and i can now retrieve all the data, but now i get 2 blanks in the select and the others rows. One of the blanks retrieves me all the data; the second blank don't do nothing.

Comment: In order to help you out, there are some missing informations on your code as I said before. We need to see how some variables are beeing set. Please add this peace of code and show what it returns after you select one option: `var_dump($grupo);` before the foreach code. If you look at it you are using the same variable that maybe was set outside the for and inside the for.

Answer (score -2):

```
$DB = new DataBase();

                $listagrupos = $DB->query(SELECT * FROM grupo);

                $DB->disconnect();
```

i think you need query or queryFunc instead of select_associative_data

Comment: Assuming you know his `DataBase` class setup? Plus, you forgot `"` around the query.

Comment: @davidath, if i use your code it brings me nothing. Using my code it retrieves me correctly the rows; the problem isn't the result itself but the lack of the select with the respective option i've selected and when i chose some option, i can't go back to all options.